# CSS - Inline-block breaks float

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` that floats left and a `<p>` that renders to the right of it. Problem is, there is no spacing between my text and my div. I tried to add margin and padding to both the div and and p but they did not work. I read that I need to first apply `inline-block` to the `p`. This made the padding and margin work but it broke the `float:left`:

```html
<div style="float: left">
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p style="margin-left: 15px; display: inline-block;"> Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. </p>
```

How to add margin to text and keep float:left of div?

Comment: The inline-block element will be as wide as it needs to be to accomodate the text...therefore 100% wide given the amount of text you have. If you want it on the right you'll need to assign a width.

Comment: Put a right margin on the div instead of a left margin on the paragraph

Comment: @j08691 I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: You also have to remove the inline-block from the paragraph to have it work

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't want to assign a width because it's a full-width design.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. If the text is too long it will force the inline-block element to be wider than the remaining space on the right and so it will drop below the float.

Comment: @j08691That's weird. I thought I had tried that already. Actually, I think I tried padding-right but it didn't work. Margin seems to be working. Will accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use `flexbox`? You will need to create a wrapping `div` and have the `ul` and `p` tags as children of that.

```css
div{ display: flex; align-items: top; justify-content: flex-start;}
p {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
  </ul>

  <p> Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him
    good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` by changing your HTML structure:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
  </ul>
  <p> Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in your example but not on my site for some reason. Probably some other style affecting it. I got it working with a margin on my div though but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the styling on the paragraph, and instead adding your margin to the right of your div seems to accomplish what you're after:

```html
<div style="float: left; margin-right:50px;">
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. Lorem ipsum killer smacks biggie smalls superman ate him good so I forgot to drain the godhead. </p>
```